# Annonymus function vs regular function performance/optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, memory-management

Was wondering which of the two examples given below would be a "proper way to do it" from an optimization standpoint. Let's assume the function in question is being run more then once obviously.

**example 1:**

```
function example(){
  //do stuff
}
setTimeout(example, 1000);
```

**example 2:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //do stuff
}, 1000);
```

Obviously the second example would have to declare a function multiple times but the function itself would be garbage collected after its invocation, whereas the example one would only declare once and then re-invoke as needed, what is more heavy however?

Comment: You could also do
    setTimeout(function example(){
        //do stuff
    }, 1000);

Comment: Do you have performance problems and actually measured that that code is your bottleneck? If not, use the code that is most readable/maintainable.

Comment: The main benefit of not doing it as per example 2 is that its easier to debug. Imagine the case when you have multiple anonymous functions, it can get a bit confusing to read a stack trace.

Comment: @Shaun `setTimeout(function myNamedFunctionExpression() { ... })`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this test case it may help you to see the difference in execution time
https://jsperf.com/anonymous-vs-defined-iv

Comment: Thank you, though obviously function is much heavier.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions have no performance benefits. They are just simpler.

I would use it if that function is very local and not being reused.

Lambda expression benefits includes:

- Free variables, ie. the variables inside goes out of scope once the function returns. (I think this is refered to as code deligation)
- Simpler to add instead of a named function.

Drawbacks are:

- Difficult to debug.
- Cannot be reused.

Comment: function is being reused and is a pretty heavy function as a part of a bigger system.

Comment: @Dellirium The difference in performance is negligible. See Ryad.iv answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has been answered, but as an afterthought:

If you are worried about polluting your scope, then you could wrap it all in an anonymous function:

```js
//Set return value of anonymous function to variable
var timer = (function() {
  //Create a function only in this scope
  //(Which is "close" to your setTimeout)
  function example() {
      console.log("test")
    }
    //Return your setTimeout call so you can manipulate it from the outside
  return setInterval(example, 100);
})();
//Interact with setTimeout
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It is a part of a much larger system, cannot wrap it like that, was just interested in the performance difference from this standpoint as it reoccurs throughout the entire system. Might be beneficial to migrate from one to the other if difference is big.